# How can I derive basic derivative identities?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I haven't taken a calculus class in a long time but last I recall you memorize things like $(\log x)' = \frac{1}{x} ~ dx$ or $(\log_a x)' = \frac{1}{x \log a} dx$ or $(a^x)' = a^x \log a ~ dx$ or $(e^x)' = e^x dx$ and so on.

After many years I had forgotten these relationships and had to memorize them again but I want to know how I could derive these kinds of rules on my own. Is there a general technique?

Comment: You can use the basic definition of derivatives that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}:=\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]$ for many until you've built up several of the basic rules such as product rule and chain rule, at which point even more complicated derivatives become easier.

Comment: You're basically asking how to derive about half of the results in a beginning calculus course. That's a long story - the best thing to do is find a calculus book. (Or notes online or whatever.)

Comment: @JMoravitz So for example $\frac{d}{dx}[\log x] := \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\log(x+h)-\log(x)}{h}$, but from there I don't really know how that changes to $\frac{1}{x} dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\begin{array}{rl}\frac{d}{dx}[\log x] &= \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\log(x+h)-\log(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\log(\frac{x+h}{x})\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\log\left((1+\frac{h}{x})^\frac{1}{h}\right)\\
&=\log(e^{\frac{1}{x}})\\
&=\frac{1}{x}
\end{array}$

Remembering that the *definition of $e$* is that $e:=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}(1+h)^{\frac{1}{h}}$ or equivalently $e:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and from there one can prove that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}(1+\alpha h)^{\frac{1}{h}}=e^\alpha$.

Using this result, let us prove that $\frac{d}{dx}[e^x]=e^x$.  To do so, let us give two different approaches to finding the derivative of the same function:

$\frac{d}{dx}[\log e^x] = \frac{d}{dx}[x\log e]=\frac{d}{dx}[x]=1$

$\frac{d}{dx}[\log e^x]=\frac{d}{dx}[e^x]\frac{1}{e^x}$ (*by chain rule*)

This shows that $\frac{d}{dx}[e^x]\frac{1}{e^x}=1$ and therefore $\frac{d}{dx}[e^x]=e^x$

The other logarithmic and exponentiation derivatives follow directly from these two and chain rule as well as from basic properties of logarithms and exponentiation.

For example, $\frac{d}{dx}[a^x] = \frac{d}{dx}[e^{\log (a^x)}]=\frac{d}{dx}[e^{x\log a}]=e^{x\log a}\log a = a^x\log a$

Answer (score 1):

How, exactly, are you **defining** "log(x)"?  How you prove the derivative or any other property of log(x) will, of course, depend upon the definition.  One common definition is "the inverse function to $e^x$", given that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, it follows that If $y= log(x)$ then $x= e^y$ so that $\frac{dx}{dy}= e^y= x$ and then that $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{x}$.

Another perfectly valid way to define the function log(x) is $log(x)= \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt$.  In that case, it follows immediately, by the "fundamental theorem of Calculus", that $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{x}$.
(Part of the "fundamental theorem of Calculus" says that if $F(x)= \int_a^x f(t)dt$ then $\frac{dF}{dx}= f(x)$.)